# thumb: true not showing thumbnail preview in keystonejs

Tags: keystonejs

I want to show at least the path of locally uploaded file ,how can I achieve in keystonejs , I found [How to show uploaded image in Keystonejs back-end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46185705/how-to-show-uploaded-image-in-keystonejs-back-end?rq=1) also I pulled ncecessary changes but it is not thumbnail preview,can someone please help me? I need this feature as a non tech person also can use this.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49942045/3405291) might be helpful.

Comment: I tried that but didn't work , I added url: true inside schema along with thumb:true then it worked.

Comment: @Priyanka were u able to find any solution to it ???